# how to get current PC register value on MIPS arch?

Tags: mips, backtrace, program-counter

I'd like to do backtrace on MIPS.
Then, I face one problem: how do I get the current PC register value, since it doesn't belong to 32 normal registers..
Thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: Can you call a dummy function that reads it off the stack? I don't know MIPS, but just an idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a subroutine that looks somewhat like:

```
.text 
.globl GetIP 

GetIP:
move $v0, $ra
jr $ra
```

And then call the routine; it'll give you the address of the first instruction after the call.

Comment: You both are right, I choose you since you are the first one ^_^

Comment: Thanks! (Need 15 chars to post)

Answer (score 3):

after a jal call it will be copied to the ra register...
so you could store ra, then jal to the next line, read ra, restore ra.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question isn't tagged `c`, I figured it might be useful to share a solution utilizing inline assembly in `gcc`.

```
__attribute__((noinline)) static void *get_pc(void)
{
    void *pc;
    asm volatile ("move %0, $ra" : "=r"(pc));
    return pc;
}
```

Of course, the gist of the solution is the same as the currently accepted answer. Since the function is very small, it is a good candidate for inlining when optimization is turned on. However, if that function were inlined, its return value would be invalid : it would simply return some value of `ra` in the calling function, since a `jal` or `jalr` wouldn't be generated, and `ra` thus not set to the instruction following `jal`/`jalr`. This is why `__attribute__((noinline))` is essential in this case.

Comment: A more portable way would be to use GCC's builtins to retrieve the return address: `__builtin_extract_return_addr (__builtin_return_address (0))` instead of the inline assembly.